# I can't make AND request with Elastic Search

Tags: php, elasticsearch, doctrine

I want to make a `AND` request with ES , So I put a `must` between terms (for `tags.id`) in my `boolQuery` , but It doesn't work ... I receive elements but like a `OR`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "computerId": [
              1
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tags",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "tags.id": [
                        1,
                        2,
                        3
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? 1 AND 2 AND 3 ?

Comment: Yes exactly, I only want objects that have the three `tags.id`

Comment: But with this query I receive all objects that match ALMOST one of `tags.id`

Comment: See my answer. let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `nested` inside your bool query.

Try this:

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "computerId": [
              1
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tags",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "tags.id": {
                  "value": 1
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tags",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "tags.id": {
                  "value": 2
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tags",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "tags.id": {
                  "value": 3
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Terms acts like OR, so your query is doing AND(1 OR 2 OR 3).

> Terms query returns documents that contain one or more exact terms in a provided field.

[From Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: 3 nesteds ? It's good practice ? I test it and I tell you. Thank you man

Comment: If your object looks like: tags:[ {id:1},{id:2},{id:3} ] then that’s the way to operate AND between inner objects.

Comment: Ah ok that's exactly the object I got, I'm looking for to build the query with 3 nested inside. Because before I got one nested which was the output of my method

Comment: Glad it works. 
Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers